# loop over json file with two lists python

Tags: python

I have a json file with two lists, how can I loop over them both?

json file:

```
{"name":["bethany", "morgan"],"city":["boston","new york","austin","los angeles"]}
```

Right now I am doing:

```
    for i in json['name']:
        if i in dict[x]:
            count += 1
```

I tried to do things like

```
for i in json['name','city']:

for i in (json['name'],json['city']):

for i in json['name']:
    for i in json['city']:

for i, j in json['name'],json['city']:
```

But that's not working. Ideally it would be nice to have the output show which are the names and which are the cities, but I really just want to be able to loop over both the lists at once.

**EDIT**

```
   for key,value in jsons.items():
        for element in value:
            if element in dict[x]:
              count += 1
        for key, value in json.items():
            for element in value:
                if element in dict[x]:
                    list_words.append(element)
```

how can i append the key to the element though in the final list so I can see which words came from names and which from city.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for, if those keys has the different meaning for you then why would you want to iterate them in the same loop. It's sounds like you are doing something that is logically wrong

Comment: No that is what I want I changed the actual names of my document, but I guess a more accurate representation would be {"name":["bethany", "morgan"],"otherNames":["sarah","josh","austin","justin"]}

Answer (score 1):

```
for key, value in your_json.items():
    for element in value:
        print(key, element)    # replace this with whatever you want to do
```

Comment: I see, but how can I add this to search for it in the dic?

Comment: Please edit your original post to say exactly what you'd like to achieve.

Comment: I added new code to my original post....how can i append the key to the element though in the final list so I can see which words came from names and which from city.